# How to force usage of specific yAxis in LinePlusBarChart of nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

The nvd3 `linePlusBarChart` allows to use multiple `yAxis`, which is also shown in their example [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html) (and in the angular-nvd3 example [here](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/linePlusBarWithFocusChart)). In the examples (see plunkers), they simply use two series of data and they are automatically mapped to one of the `yAxis` each. For me, this doesn't happen though.

My data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Series 1",
    "bars": true,
    "values": [ [1425942000, 20], [1425942040, 25], ... ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Series 2",
    "bars": true,
    "values": [ [1425942000, 80], [1425942040, 40], ... ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Series 3",
    "bars": true,
    "values": [ [1425942000, 37], [1425942040, 55], ... ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Series 4",
    "values": [ [1425942000, 20132.44], [1425942040, 40032.93], ... ]
  }
]
```

So from the data it should be clear that there needs to be a second `yAxis` to be used for the fourth series because of the huge difference in scale.

The chart configuration looks like this (be aware that it is a configuration for angular-nvd3):

```
{
    type: 'linePlusBarChart',
    height: 500,
    margin : {
        top: 50,
        right: 75,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 50
    },
    xAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Time',
        tickFormat: function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%Y/%m/%d')(new Date(d));
        }
    },
    x2Axis: {
        tickFormat: function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%b %Y')(new Date(d));
        }
    },
    y1Axis: {
        axisLabel: 'Just some numbers here',
        axisLabelDistance: -10,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
            return d3.format(',')(d);
        }
    },
    y2Axis: {
        axisLabel: 'Some money numbers',
        axisLabelDistance: 10,
        width: 100,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
            return '$ ' + d3.format(',.2f')(d);
        }
    },
    y3Axis: {},
    y4Axis: {},
    bars: {
        forceY: [0],
        padData: true
    },
    bars2: {
        forceY: [0],
        padData: true
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to find out how to force some data series to attach themselves to a certain `yAxis`. Currently, all four series are attached to the right axis.

I already tried adding a `yAxis: 1` (or `yAxis: 2`) attribute on the series objects, which is the way it is done for other chart types, but it doesn't work.

So if anyone has some advice for me, I'd really appreciate it.

Bonus question: Is there some way to achieve the same as `useInteractiveGuideline: true` does on `lineChart` for the `linePlusBarChart` I want/need to use?

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake myself. The series should use `bar: true` and not `bars: true`, then both `yAxis` are used.

```
[
  {
    "key": "Series 1",
    "bar": true,   <-- instead of `"bars": true`
    "values": [ [1425942000, 20], [1425942040, 25], ... ]
  },
  ...
]
```